# passing callback function into onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive been messing with this a while and have tried numerous ways. It still wont work.

```
function popupConfirm(widtH, texT, callback){ 
var top=(window.innerHeight/2) - 100;
var left=(window.innerWidth/2) - (widtH/2);
var r="<div id='standard-modal' style='width:"+widtH+"px;top:"+top+"px;left:"+left+"px;'>";
        r+="<div id='standard-modal-header' style='width:"+(widtH-4)+"px;'>";
        r+="<strong>&rarr; &nbsp; Icon Box &nbsp; &larr;</strong>";
        r+="</div>";
        r+="<div id='standard-modal-message' style='width:"+(widtH-30)+"px;'>"+texT+"</div>";
            r+="<div id='button_wrapper'><div id='standard-modal-button' class='left_button' onclick='$(\"#standard-modal\").remove();' >CANCEL</div>";

            // following line attaches callback to onclick event        
            r+="<div id='standard-modal-button' class='right_button' onclick='callback();' >CONFRIM</div></div>";
        r+="<div style='clear:both;'></div></div>";

$('body').append(r);
}


popupConfirm(300,'blah blah' , function(){alert("finally");});
```

in theory, i want it to do the alert once the user clicks confirm in my popup...  any help is appreciated.

its logs to the console 'callback is not defined'

Comment: what is it supposed to do, and how does it 'not work'.

Comment: as i said, its supposed to do the alert when the user clicks confirm. what its doing is logging 'callback is not defined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic scoping problem, when you append your string to the body then the user clicks on the div the onclick is trying to fire a function called `window.callback()`. Instead of using inline javascript which isn't a good idea in general anyways is bind the click handler after the html is created.

```
...
        // following line attaches callback to onclick event        
        r+="<div id='standard-modal-button' class='right_button'>CONFRIM</div></div>";
    r+="<div style='clear:both;'></div></div>";

    $('body').append(r);
    $('#standard-modal-button').bind('click', callback);
}
```

Comment: this is a great idea. it works perfectly. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I would use click() instead of trying to put the callback in your function.

```
$('.right_button').on('click', function() {
    alert("finally");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know where to begin telling you what to change, except for everything. First I'd start off actually creating that `div` as part of the page and hide it. When it should be shown; you can simply do `$('#standard-modal').show();`. You can then do what has been suggested in other answers like :

```
$('#cancel-btn').click(function(){
    alert('your message');
});
```

If you are still having issues, check out jqueryUI http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score -1):

a bit dangerous but:

```
 r+="<div id='standard-modal-button' class='right_button' onclick='eval('(" + callback.toString() + ")()');' >CONFRIM</div></div>";
```

Comment: Why in the world is `eval` necessary?